# time complexity for naive quick union algorithm

Tags: time-complexity, union-find

how can I calculate the worst case of quick-union algorithm.
Actually, I am always struggled in time complexity when tree height is involved in. I know it is related to O(h), However the tree is developing in the code.

So what should be the correct way ?

Comment: Which heuristics, if any, are you using (union by rank? path compression?) These analyses can be highly nontrivial!

Comment: hi,just basic implementation, No optimization involved